# sum the anothers rows value to the row in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, select

The below table contained place name and distance KM, the row having KM between the previous row to place i.e The Place B have KM from A to B, c having the KM from B
  I want to find the total distance each place to each place in SQL

```
Place   Distane in KM
A --->  0
B --->  80
C --->  90
D --->  100
```

I want to print the result as

```
Place   --->  To    --->  Distane in KM 
A --->  B   --->  80
A   --->  C --->  170
A   --->  D --->  270
B   --->  C --->  90
B   --->  D --->  190
C   --->  D --->  100
```

Comment: How do you determine what the "previous" row is?

Comment: @melpomene i have alphanumeric unique id from a row

Comment: That does not answer my question. My question is about ordering, not uniqueness.

Comment: to removing the alpha value from id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could self-join the table on rows where the destination is larger than the source, and use the window variant of `sum`:

```
SELECT   src.place + '->' + dst.place, 
         SUM(dst.distance) OVER (PARTITION BY src.place ORDER BY dst.place)
FROM     distances src
JOIN     distances dst ON src.place < dst.place
ORDER BY 1, 2
```

[**SQLFiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/20a47/2/0)

Comment: Thanks!!! @Mureinik  i can able to run this with partition order by cause, if i add the order by cause i receive an error <i>Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
Incorrect syntax near 'order'. </i.> and i received wrong output with out  order by cause

Comment: @user154870 what [tag:rdbms] are you using?

Comment: @user154870 ... line 14? This code only has 5 lines.

Comment: SQL Server 2008 line number 14 have the order by cause

Comment: @user154870 I've edited the code and the SQLFiddle to use [tag:sql-sever] syntax. I don't have access to such a version of SQL-Server, so I'm not sure if it would work there or not. Regardless, I sincerely recommend upgrading - this version is about a decade old...

Comment: Thanks!!!! i will try other possibility  or i will do the upgrade version

Answer (score 0):

**First you have to tag your DBMS like `sql-server` or `oracle`**

---

It's demo for sql-server version and using `row_number function` with your order logic -> `cross join self` -> `sum distance`.

```
with CTE as (
  select *,row_number() over (order by [Place]) rnk
  from T
)
select t1.Place + '->' + t2.Place as Place
  ,(select sum(Distane) from CTE t3 where t3.rnk > t1.rnk and t3.rnk <= t2.rnk  ) distance
from CTE t1,CTE t2
where t2.rnk > t1.rnk
order by Place
```

---

**Result:**

```
| Place | distance |
|-------|----------|
|  A->B |       80 |
|  A->C |      170 |
|  A->D |      270 |
|  B->C |       90 |
|  B->D |      190 |
|  C->D |      100 |
```

---

**Test DDL:**

```
CREATE TABLE T
    ([Place] varchar(1), [Distane] int)
;

INSERT INTO T
    ([Place], [Distane])
VALUES
    ('A', 0),
    ('B', 80),
    ('C', 90),
    ('D', 100)
;
```

---

### [Test DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/52596/23/0)

Comment: Thanks @IT WeiHan  its working, i want use this result in joins with master table